# Windows 8 Install DVD won't run

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8, so I downloaded the ISO and burned it to a DVD.

However, when I try to run it nothing happens. I get the dialog asking me if I want to allow the program to run but nothing happens.

The disk works if I boot from CD/DVD. However, when asked if I want to do a clean install or an upgrade it tells me that I have to boot to windows and run the DVD.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have UAC turned on?

Comment: I turned it off.

Comment: Have you checked the download checksum? (I had that problem once; it even got 78% through install before it would fail.) Did you verify the ISO burnt correctly on the DVD?

Answer (score 1):

- Check the checksum of the ISO that you originally downloaded and
  burnt to DVD.
- If it checks out, try checking the checksum of the DVD.
- If *that's* correct, when you run the 8 install program from 7, make
  sure to right-click the setup program and hit "Run as Administrator".

It is also a good idea to look in Task Manager/Process Explorer or another monitor.  Do you see the setup process appearing and disappearing?  Does it stay on the screen?  Never appear?  This can help diagnose problems.